# Can I use "was" twice in this sentence.

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

If there was one thing that every commanding officer in the special operations community knew about, it was just how much red tape it took to mount a rescue mission of that magnitude.

Comment: Sure. Why not? One in the condition clause, one in the consequence clause.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can use it twice in this context! There is no rule against it.

However, you should always look out for ways to make your writing more concise! This can often delete those pesky, repeated words from your sentences.

For example, a shorter way to write your sentence (and eliminate 1 "was") is:

> The number one thing every special operations commanding officer knew about was how much red tape it took to mount a rescue mission of that magnitude.

or,

> One thing that every commanding officer in the special operations community knew about was just how much red tape it took to mount a rescue mission of that magnitude.

Here's a website with tips to do that throughout your whole paper: https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CCS/ClearConciseSentences.html

However, as I said before, your sentence is still correct and usable! Great job!